# CredMartialCredentials username hint (smartcard)

Tags: c++, windows, cryptography, smartcard

I am attempting to use `CredMartialCredential` and `LogonUser` to get an access token for a user account using a smartcard. There are two accounts which can authenticate with the smartcard (described (kinda) [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/08/10/mapping-one-smartcard-certificate-to-multiple-accounts/)).

I was able to get it halfway working by following [this](https://www.idrix.fr/Root/Samples/SmartCardLogon.cpp) source, but it seems to only work when transitioning from the mapped account to the account matching the CN on the certificate. As a consequence of the multiple-users-one-smartcard setup there is no UPN configured on the card.

According to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2014/10/09/programmatic-smartcard-logons-in-windows/) you have to use `LsaLogonUser` with `KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON` but the documentation for both of those is obtuse and doesn't have examples. I found [this](https://www.idrix.fr/Root/Samples/LsaSmartCardLogon.cpp) but it seems like you need `SeTcbPrivilege` to use it... I attempted to implement, but I am getting c000006d:c0000321 (STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE, STATUS_SMARTCARD_SUBSYSTEM_FAILURE)

Thanks!

Comment: So your question is: "How to implement smart card logon where the smart card is shared between accounts??" And that needs to be working for a specific Windows version?

Comment: Essentially, but I figured it out. The last link works, but you need to specify the correct key container.

Comment: If you have found an answer, would you be so kind to answer this question yourself? Happy to vote up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `LsaLogonUser` in a situation where multiple users are authenticated using the same smartcard key, you must supply the username in the `KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON`. This is demonstrated by the link provided in my question.
If there are multiple keys on the smartcard, it will select the first one and fail if that is not the key used for windows login. 
You must supply the container name in the `KERB_CERTIFICATE_LOGON` (also included in the example but left blank).

You will also want to replace the CSP name (`WCHAR szCspName[] = L"IDRIX Generic Cryptographic Service Provider";`) with `Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider`.

It is possible to use `LsaConnectUntrusted` if you do not have `SeTcbPrivilege` (replace the call to `LsaRegisterLogonProcess`). However, you will not able to do anything with the token you get from `LsaLogonUser` unless you start out with the `Impersonate a client after authentication` privilege.

Good Luck, this API is awful.